# Powershell parameter to variables into a command

Tags: variables, powershell, parameters, operators

I tried to find a way to join or use variable into a command.
I'm trying to create a command that accept parameters:
The command: `aduser.ps1 John`

aduser.ps1 script:
`Param($User)`
`Get-AdUser -filter 'Name -like "*$user*"'`

I had error and not sure what operator to use to join in the `$user` variables, i tried + or & and not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables will not expand inside single quote strings, replace them with double quotes:

```
Get-AdUser -filter "Name -like '*$user*'"
```

Comment: Lol, I did not know that you could open with double quote and close with single quote. Thats works....

Comment: See the about_Quoting_Rules topic http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx for more information.